# Ploting bianary (presence/absence) data with ggplot2 geom_point()

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

Trying to plot presence/absence data with geom_point() ggplot.

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
Name Case 1
Name Case2 0
Name Case3 1
Name2 Case 1
Name2 Case2 0
Name2 Case3 1
```

I tried:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

plot <- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Col2, y=Col1, fill = Col3, size = 7)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = .1, vjust=0.5))
```

And it just turns out that all of the spaces are filled in::
[image: None of the 0 in the dataframe are respected and all of the spaces are filled]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fill` is not a property of `geom_point`, unless you specifically set a point shape that respects it.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Col2, y=Col1, fill = factor(Col3))) +
  geom_point(size = 7, shape = 21)
```

[image]

(You need to set `size` in `geom_point`, outside the `aes`.)

Alternatively, you could change the `shape` by `Col3`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Col2, y=Col1, shape = factor(Col3))) +
  geom_point(size = 7) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(1, 16))
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful ! The fill works wonderful for the eyes too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What about using colour? `ggplot(aes(x=Col2, y=Col1, fill = Col3, colour = Col3, size = 7))`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking just to show the absence or presence then maybe changing the alpha will work.

```
df<- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Col1 Col2 Col3
Name Case 1
Name Case2 0
Name Case3 1
Name2 Case 1
Name2 Case2 0
Name2 Case3 1")

library(ggplot2)

#need to convert col3 from a continuous value to a discrete value.
ggplot(df, aes(x=Col2, y=Col1, alpha = factor(Col3) )) +
  geom_point(size = 10) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = .1, vjust=0.5))
```

Another option is to use the color aesthetic and define a custom color palette of "White" and another color(s).

[image]